# DocsList.createFolder() creates an extra folder named 'undefined'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to create a simple function that creates a folder. The parameter of the function is to be the name of the new folder. When I attempt to do this, the function creates the folder as desired, but it also creates an extra folder named "undefined".

```
create("myTestFolder"); // I've also tried explicitly declaring a variable as a string and
                        // then passing that variable

function create(name)
{
    Logger.log(name); // Discussed below.
    DocsList.createFolder(name);
};
```

When I examine the contents of the log, I see the intended string, but I also see a second line containing the text "undefined", which is consistent with the results that I am seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks awkward. After saving this you're running the "create" function from the menu? Then your create function will indeed be called twice. Once on the script initialization, since you call it directly from the global scope, then again, actually triggered by the Run menu, where the `name` parameter will indeed be undefined.

I think you should change it to something like this:

```js
function testCreate() {
  create("myTestFolder");
}

function create(name) {
  Logger.log(name);
  DocsList.createFolder(name);
}
```

Then, from the Run menu, call `testCreate` instead of `create`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. And thanks for the succinct explanation as to why I was seeing that result.